# How to fix Flutter version solving null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I was on Flutter 1.20.4 stable. But now after upgrade to 1.22.1 stable I have nullsafety error when try build:

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1 and exampleproject depends on path 1.7.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because exampleproject depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
```

How I can solve? I must update everything for nullsafety?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your pubspec.yaml file in this thread?

Until then, can you make sure that pubspec for **flutter_test** looks like this:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and the **environment** entry looks like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes my flutter_test and environment look like that. How to solve?

Comment: yes, like I asked, can you please paste your entire pubspec.yaml file into this thread, so that I can take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: I also should mention do not include the package id. I only want to see how your pubspec is organised. It could be an identation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the downgrading flutter solution, If you are the owner of exampleproject and can make the changes within it, you could try changing the pubspec.yaml of example project from path 1.7.0-nullsafety to match the version expected by flutter_test.